# find all second partial derivatives of $\arctan(\frac{x+y}{1-xy})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given $f(x,y)=\arctan(\frac{x+y}{1-xy})$

find:

$f_{xx}$
$f_{yy}$
$f_{xy}$
$f_{yx}$

I checked other questions but they are not helpful I need the answer, I prefer working backwards

Comment: well the derivative with respect to x is $tan(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$ times the quortient rule on the inside which $\frac{1*(1-xy)-[(-y)(x+xy)]}{(1-xy^)2}$ I think?

Comment: which is insane to calculate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first partial derivatives simplify quite a bit:

$$\begin{align}f_x(x,y)&=[1+(\frac{x+y}{1-xy})^2]^{-1}[\frac{(1-xy)-(x+y)(-y)}{(1-xy)^2}]\\&=[1+(\frac{(x+y)^2}{(1-xy)^2})]^{-1}[\frac{1+y^2}{(1-xy)^2}]\\&=[(1-xy)^2+(x+y)^2]^{-1}[1+y^2]\\&=[1-2xy+x^2y^2+x^2+2xy+y^2]^{-1}[1+y^2]\\&=[y^2(x^2+1)+(x^2+1)]^{-1}[y^2+1]\\&=[(y^2+1)(x^2+1)]^{-1}[y^2+1]\\&=(x^2+1)^{-1}\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}f_y(x,y)&=[1+(\frac{x+y}{1-xy})^2]^{-1}[\frac{(1-xy)-(x+y)(-x)}{(1-xy)^2}]\\&=[1+(\frac{(x+y)^2}{(1-xy)^2})]^{-1}[\frac{1+x^2}{(1-xy)^2}]\\&=[(1-xy)^2+(x+y)^2]^{-1}[1+x^2]\\&=[1-2xy+x^2y^2+x^2+2xy+y^2]^{-1}[1+x^2]\\&=[y^2(x^2+1)+(x^2+1)]^{-1}[x^2+1]\\&=[(y^2+1)(x^2+1)]^{-1}[x^2+1]\\&=(y^2+1)^{-1}\end{align}$$

Now I'll leave it to you for the second partial derivatives.

Comment: Thank you dave you saved my skin on that problem

Answer (score 2):

Hint...note that $$f(x,y)=\arctan x+\arctan y$$

Answer (score 0):

Divide and conquer.

Let $g(x,y)=\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}$; then
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=
\frac{(1-xy)-(x+y)(-y)}{(1-xy)^2}=\frac{1+y^2}{(1-xy)^2}
$$
By symmetry,
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=\frac{1+x^2}{(1-xy)^2}
$$
Since
$$
\frac{1}{1+g(x,y)^2}=\frac{(1-xy)^2}{(1-xy)^2+(x+y)^2}=
\frac{(1-xy)^2}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}
$$
we have, by the chain rule,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{1+y^2}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}
\qquad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{1+x^2}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}
$$